# How to change parent hook from child function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 components:

- addCircle (Parent)
- deleteCircle (Child)

I have number hook - which counts every function execution (adding)

I passing this hook to child component (as props.number), in the child component i need to convert it (substract 1 or equal to 0)

How can I modify state from child component?

CODE:

addCircle:

```
    const CircleForm = () => {

        const[number, setNumbers] = useState(0)

        const addCircle = (number) =>{
            setNumbers(number = number +1);

        }

  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => addCircle(number)}  className ="primary-button"> Add figure</button>
       <DeleteCircleForm number = {number}/>
    </div>
   )
}
```

deleteCircle:

```
const DeleteCircleForm = props => {

const deleteCircle = props =>{
    //error here and problem with passing props
    props.number = props.number -1;
}

const deleteAllCircle = props =>{
    //error here and problem with passing props
    props.number = 0;
}


  return (
    <div>
      {props.number}
     <button onClick={() => deleteCircle(props.number)}  className ="secondary-button"> Delete figure</button> 
      <button onClick={() => deleteAllCircle(props.number)}  className ="secondary-button"> Delete All figures</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DeleteCircleForm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to pass functions from parent to children like this:

**Parent**

```
const CircleForm = () => {

    const[number, setNumbers] = useState(0)

    const addCircle = (number) =>{
            setNumbers(number = number +1);
    }

    const deleteCircle = () =>{    
        setNumbers(number - 1)
    }

    const deleteAllCircle = () =>{    
        setNumbers(0)
    }

  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => addCircle(number)}  className ="primary-button"> Add figure</button>
       <DeleteCircleForm number={number} deleteCircle={deleteCircle} deleteAllCircle={deleteAllCircle}/>
    </div>
   )
}
```

**Children**

```
const DeleteCircleForm = props => {

  return (
    <div>
      {props.number}
     <button onClick={props.deleteCircle}  className ="secondary-button"> Delete figure</button> 
      <button onClick={props.deleteAllCircle}  className ="secondary-button"> Delete All figures</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```